# fish shell + WebStorm terminal: how to use Alt + backspace to delete entire word

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, webstorm, key-bindings, fish

I am trying out WebStorm and I use fish as my default shell. I am using macOS.

In VSCode's integrated terminal, iTerm2, and terminal my fish shell works as I want it: it deletes an entire word with <kbd>Alt + backspace</kbd>.

When I am in WebStorm's integrated terminal this does not work. I have not been able to find any solution to this problem.

How can I get <kbd>Alt + backspace</kbd> to delete an entire word (kill-word) in WebStorm's integrated terminal?

I have tried changing the key bindings for fish shell.

In iTerm2:

1. fish_key_reader & pressing `Alt backspace`

```
Press a key:
bind \e\x7F 'do something'
```

2. bind \e\x7F backward-kill-word

Comment: What does fish_key_reader say in Webstorm's integrated terminal?

Comment: Thanks @faho . Doing the same thing in WebStorm's integrated terminal fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the same commands in WebStorm's integrated terminal solved my problem.

In WebStorm's integrated terminal: (put this in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` to keep the setting after restart and do not only run the command in a terminal!)

1. `fish_key_reader` & pressing Alt backspace

```
Press a key:
bind \e\x7F 'do something'
```

2. `bind \e\x7F backward-kill-word`

Comment: This is the *exact same thing* as in iTerm, and you even have the same typo in both - `\x7f` vs `\z7f`. Your problem isn't with the bindings, your problem is that the Jetbrains IDE fish integration is apparently *still* broken. I was hoping they'd fixed it - the issues I know, like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-299501/Shell-integration-breaks-with-fish-shell, are marked as "fixed". Either you need to update or it's not actually fixed

Comment: This is assuming you *have* added the `bind` command to config.fish or similar. If you just ran it interactively you need to store it so it is run on startup.

Comment: Fixed the typo. I see re fix it so it runs on startup - I only ran it interactively. I will look up how to add the `bind` command to fish config (or however it is done).